# Select last ordered value for each distinct key in a table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with three columns: `key`, `value` and `timestamp`, the `key` column is indexed, the data looks like:

```
 key | value |      timestamp  
-----+-------+---------------------
  A  |  1.3  | 2018-12-30 00:00:00
  A  |  1.1  | 2018-12-29 00:00:00
  C  |  1.1  | 2019-01-02 00:00:00
  B  |  0.1  | 2019-01-02 00:00:00
  B  |  0.3  | 2018-12-30 00:00:00
  A  |  1.1  | 2018-12-31 00:00:00 
  B  |  0.2  | 2019-01-01 00:00:00
  A  |  0.9  | 2019-01-02 00:00:00
```

How to select the earliest value for each distinct `key` in the table?
I need these output:

```
 key | value |      timestamp  
-----+-------+---------------------
  A  |  1.1  | 2018-12-29 00:00:00
  B  |  0.3  | 2018-12-30 00:00:00
  C  |  1.1  | 2019-01-02 00:00:00
```

Comment: Unrelated, but `timestamp` is a misleading name for a date column, since a timestamp includes hour, minutes and seconds as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (key) t.*
from t
order by key, timestamp;
```

This is normally the most efficient method in Postgres.  In particular, it can take advantage of an index on `(key, timestamp)` for performance.